# Is the universe abundant?

Tags: universe

Is the universe abundant enough for accommodating everyone? If we compare it with a pie, should we never feel insecure that someone might get a bigger share of the pie? Because the pie is abundant and we can get how much ever we want.

Comment: There are, I believe, large clouds of H20 in deep space. Moreover, *Star Trek*'s food-creation technology is not entirely fantastical, in principle. Max Tegmark has proposed a sphaleron-based energy system whereby baryons could be converted into leptons (or *vice versa*, IIRC), which would hopefully be a profound "fuel source" in the (distant) future (if it can truly be engineered, anyway).

Comment: The spiritual principle is that there is enough for everyone if they care for each other. It is a perfect example of Game Theory results, written as large as a continent.

Answer (score 1):

What determines something's scarcity or abundance is whether you can get it, and how much you'd have to give up in order to get it, not how much of it exists. If the Moon was made entirely out of pie, it wouldn't change the scarcity of pie one bit, because you'd have to give up millions of pies worth of resources to get a slice of pie from the Moon down to your plate.

Comment: The universe brims over with materials for life, but the organizing structure that makes things live seems to be unique to this planet so far.

Answer (score 0):

Q. *Is the universe abundant?*

If the universe arose from some fundamental constituents that give rise to particles (and space-time) it would be abundant but your point of view would still be unique, and how much pie you comprehend depends on that.